# Find active and inactive students with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join

I have a  list of `students` in students table, and a list of their courses in `students_courses` table, and each of these courses may be active or inactive.
I'm wondering if there is a quick way to find "active" users, which means they have at least 1 active course (sc.`active` = 1) and also inactive users. inactive users are those who don't have a course (there is not a row) or all of their courses are `active` = 0

also I want to get the row count before getting the actual list.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear if you want this in two separate queries or in one query (in which case the row count is just going to be *all* students).

Comment: @liquorvicar I wan't it in two queries. One for getting all rows. and one for just counting them

Comment: You don't need two queries to get data and count how many rows. You have two options: get all data (active and inactive students) in one query and count in your application (i.e. using PHP), or get active and inactive students in separate queries and count the results of each query separately.

Answer (score 1):

This query might be a little slow since it uses subqueries, but assuming you have a field `studentId` you might use this:

```
SELECT
   students.*,
   IF (
       studentId IN (
           SELECT
               studentId
           FROM
               students_courses
           WHERE
               active=1
   ),1,0) AS hasCourses
FROM
    students
```

Comment: It only does if you move the subquery into the where clause. But then you'd need two queries total: One to retrieve the students (including hasCourses), one to retrieve the COUNT for students with active courses. And then you can substract the number of students with courses from the total number of students. Not sure, if this is the best way, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(students_courses.active) as sum, student_id FROM 
    students JOIN students_courses 
    ON students.student_id =  students_courses.student_id
    GROUP BY students_courses.student_id
```

if sum = 0 this means no courses
and is its greater than 0 means some courses

for inactive users get all the student_id which are not in student_course

```
SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE student_id NOT IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCTROW student_id FROM students)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this, but I don't wanna do it in php. I to count it in mysql. `HAVING` does the trick but not for count(...)